# JSON - Get more than 25 videos from youtube playlist

Tags: html, json, youtube

I've got an html page that currently displays the videos of a playlist but it's only returning the first 25 videos:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>   
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.youtubepopup.js"></script> 
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
    $(window).load(function () {
        var playListURL = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/A6A0F817C1771FE5?v=2&alt=json&callback=?';
        var videoURL = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=';
        $.getJSON(playListURL, function (data) {
            var list_data = "";
            var column_count = -1;
            var begin_table = "<table width='100%'><tr>";
            var end_table = "</table>";
            var html_data = "";
            $.each(data.feed.entry, function (i, item) {
                column_count = column_count + 1;
                var feedTitle = item.title.$t;
                var feedURL = item.link[1].href;
                var fragments = feedURL.split("/");
                var videoID = fragments[fragments.length - 2];
                var url = videoURL + videoID;
                var thumb = "http://img.youtube.com/vi/" + videoID + "/default.jpg";

                if(column_count <= 3)
                    html_data += '<td><a class="youtube" href="#" rel="' + videoID + '" title="' + feedTitle + '"><img alt="' + feedTitle + '" src="' + thumb + '"></a></td>';
                else
                {
                    column_count = 0;
                    html_data += "</tr><tr>";
                    html_data += '<td><a class="youtube" href="#" rel="' + videoID + '" title="' + feedTitle + '"><img alt="' + feedTitle + '" src="' + thumb + '"></a></td>';
                }
            });
            html_data = begin_table + html_data + end_table;
            $(html_data).appendTo(".vidz");
            $("a.youtube").YouTubePopup({ autoplay: 1 });
        });
    });//]]>
</script>
```

Anyone know how to get the rest of the videos?  There's 27 (I believe) in this playlist.  I don't have much exprience with json so I'm kinda stuck atm.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to define the max-results in your request, only 25 are returned by default.

http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/reference.html#max-resultssp

The following snippet is returning 28 results:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>   
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
    $(window).load(function () {
        var playListURL = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/A6A0F817C1771FE5?v=2&alt=json&max-results=50';
        var videoURL = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=';
        $.getJSON(playListURL, function (data) {
            var list_data = "";
            var column_count = -1;
            var begin_table = "<table width='100%'><tr>";
            var end_table = "</table>";
            var html_data = "";
            $.each(data.feed.entry, function (i, item) {
                column_count = column_count + 1;
                var feedTitle = item.title.$t;
                var feedURL = item.link[1].href;
                var fragments = feedURL.split("/");
                var videoID = fragments[fragments.length - 2];
                var url = videoURL + videoID;
                var thumb = "http://img.youtube.com/vi/" + videoID + "/default.jpg";

                if(column_count <= 3)
                    html_data += '<td><a class="youtube" href="#" rel="' + videoID + '" title="' + feedTitle + '"><img alt="' + feedTitle + '" src="' + thumb + '"></a></td>';
                else
                {
                    column_count = 0;
                    html_data += "</tr><tr>";
                    html_data += '<td><a class="youtube" href="#" rel="' + videoID + '" title="' + feedTitle + '"><img alt="' + feedTitle + '" src="' + thumb + '"></a></td>';
                }
            });
            html_data = begin_table + html_data + end_table;
            $(html_data).appendTo(".vidz");
            });
    });//]]>
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="vidz"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried this and it seems to split the data.feed.entry into 25 "chunks", so I'm guessing I would have to use start-index somehow but I'm a little lost with all that.

Comment: When I enter the following, I get more than 25 results
[https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/A6A0F817C1771FE5?max-results=50&v=2&alt=json](https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/A6A0F817C1771FE5?max-results=50&v=2&alt=json)

Comment: when I plug that url in, it doesn't work:
[link](http://jsfiddle.net/u5Anv/) - JSFiddle

Comment: Disregard last comment...JSFiddle seems to have weird "Paste" properties and it added the word 'var' to the beginning of the line...works great.  Thanks a bunch!